# Firebase query with orderbychild and equalto (value, key) doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase database structure is like this

```
items = [
 id{
 country: value
 likes: value
 ...
 }
]
```

I want to query items sorted by likes and filtered by country
So I use query orderByChild("likes").equalTo(value, "country").limitToFirst(100)

Android code:

```
DatabaseReference ref = mDatabase.child(remotePath);

Query recentList = ref.orderByChild("likes");

if(!country.equals("")){
    recentList = recentList.equalTo(country, "country").limitToFirst(100);
}
recentList.addListenerForSingleValueEvent();
```

But this doesn't return any result. Is there a way for with to work?
My preference is to get this to work with firebase query and not change my database structure as it is already being used.

Comment: can you show a bit of your code? ... it also looks like there are very similar questions about this same topic (see Related questions on this page)

Comment: @martin, Added code snip. I could not find any other exact question or answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are ordering your query with `orderByChild("/*some child*/")` the `equalTo(/*some value*/)` method refers to that specified child. You are using the optional `key` parameter wrong.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34051326/7381466) and the Firebase docs to read more about the optional `key` parameter of `equalTo`.

Comment: Thanks. It seems Firebase Android documentation doesn't mention what is present in web documention. Well I guess I will handle the sorting part locally.